# Cannot login to heroku using cmd due to error with proxy

Tags: node.js, http, heroku, https, proxy

I'm following the Node.js Getting Started section of the Heroku docs, and when I true to run `heroku login`, it displays:
`Post https://api.heroku.com/login: http: error connecting to proxy https://proxy.server.com:3000: dial tcp: lookup proxy.server.com: getaddrinfow: No such host is known.`

The docs tell me to run `set HTTPS_PROXY=https://proxy.server.com:portnumber` in order to fix this if I have a firewall that requires a proxy to connect with external HTTP/HTTPS services (which I'm assuming I do)

I'm not sure which portnumber to use when I run this command.
When I try 3000 it gives:

```
ECONNRESET: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxy.server.com             proxy.server.com:3000
```

So I'm not exactly sure why I can't login, and also why that particular error pops up when I run the given command `set HTTPS_PROXY=https://proxy.server.com:portnumber` to resolve it (nor do I actually know what the given command does)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely do not need to set this unless you are *absolutely sure* you are behind a firewall that specifically blocks the IP `api.heroku.com` resolves to. The `https://proxy.server.com:portnumber` is just an example and could be something completely different.

Since you don't seem to understand what this does, you likely do not need to set this. Are you able to connect when you **are not** setting the proxy?

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up! I tried logging in again without setting the proxy and it worked, not sure why it didn't work the first time